# rails `form_with` `redirect_to` 303 `:see_other` makes the request does not redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect

I have a Rails form on a "show" view that looks something like:

```rb
<%= form_with(url: "/relative-path-to-index-view", method: "post") do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The `create` action of the controller responsible for handling the form submit looks like this:

```rb
def create
  redirect_to action: "index", status: :see_other
end
```

When I submit the form, I see in the network tab that it made the POST request, received a 303 `:see_other` response, and then made a `GET` request to the `index` action. However, the end-user doesn't see any redirect in the browser. Any ideas on why?

[image: Firefox network tab]

Answer (score 2):

✅ This was fixed by simply appending `local: true` to the form_with parameters.

```
- <%= form_with(url: "/relative-path-to-index-view", method: "post") do |f| %>
+ <%= form_with(url: "/relative-path-to-index-view", method: "post", local: true) do |f| %>
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

[image: Rails Docs Guidance for local: true]